# Inconsistent inheritance of interfaces with generic classes

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Take a class hierarchy `Chef extends Person extends GraphNode`, where each parent class is generic in an interface `T` that extends the interface of its parent class. The uppermost (abstract) class defines a method accepting as its argument a *subset* of the keys of `T`.

I'm seeing an error (highlighted below) when keys are a subset derived from `T`. When the derived keys are exactly `keyof T`, the code works as expected. As far as I can tell both should work – and it's notable that it *does* work in the final class `Chef`, which is not generic.

Inheritance extensions are not behaving as I'd expect, have I missed something there?

```js
type Literal = boolean | number | string;
type LiteralKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Literal ? K : never }[keyof T];

interface IPerson { name: string; friend: Person; }
interface IChef extends IPerson { specialty: string; }

export abstract class GraphNode<T extends {} = {}> {
    // set<K extends keyof T>(_key: K, _value: T[K]) { /* ... */ }     // ✅
    set<K extends LiteralKeys<T>>(_key: K, _value: T[K]) { /* ... */ } // ❌
}

export abstract class Person<T extends IPerson = IPerson> extends GraphNode<T> {
    setName(name: string) {
        this.set('name', name); // ❌ Argument of type 'string' is 
        // ... not assignable to parameter of type 'LiteralKeys<T>'.
    }
}

export class Chef extends Person<IChef> {
    setSpecialty(specialty: string) {
        this.set('specialty', specialty); // ✅
    }
}

const sam = new Chef();
sam.setName('Sam');
sam.setSpecialty('BBQ');
```

https://tsplay.dev/mAvLkW

Comment: The compiler can't do the higher order logic to figure out what `LiteralKeys<T>` is going to be when `T` is an unresolved generic type like it is inside the body of `setName()`.  Heck, I can't even do it easily, since weird things can happen when `T` is an arbitrary subtype of `IPerson`. Assuming it's fine, you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2EQVW) to soothe the compiler, by saying `this` can be treated as `Person<IPerson>` instead of `Person<T>` for some unresolved `T extends IPerson`.  If that works for you I can maybe write up an answer; otherwise let me know what's missing.

Comment: Thanks! I don't plan to do any weird(er) things with my interface inheritance  – i.e. once a key is defined by a parent interface, the child interface will never override that. So I can kind of see why the compiler is conservative but `(this as Person).set('name', name);` should be fine for me. The only workaround I'd found otherwise was `this.set('name' as any, name)` and your suggestion is clearly better there.

Comment: What is `IAttributes` doing?  It's... weird.  `Record<any, any>` is not helpful, and `LiteralKeys<{[k: string]: any}>` is going to be `string`, which will absorb any other string literal.  TypeScript can't represent "`string` except for `"blah"`" so if you have a `blah` property not extending `Literal` you're still going to get `string` out of that.  Can your remove it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBeYDw) so I can answer the question?

Comment: If I switch to `{}` ESLint complains about `Don't use {} as a type. {} actually means "any non-nullish value".` ... and suggests using a Record instead. But it's all the same to me and I'd be fine with removing `IAttribute`.

Comment: So should I change `interface IPerson extends IAttributes { name: string; friend: Person; }` to `interface IPerson { name: string; friend: Person; }` ?

Comment: Just made the change. ✅

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `LiteralKeys<T>` defined like

```
type LiteralKeys<T> = 
  { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Literal ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

is a combination of [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).  When you pass in a `T` that's some specific type like `IPerson`, the compiler can evaluate it right away:

```
type EagerlyEvaluated = LiteralKeys<IPerson> // "name"
```

But when `T` is or depends upon an unspecified type parameter, such as inside the body of `setName()`, it has to *defer* evaluation, and as such it stays mostly unevaluated:

```
function deferred<T extends IPerson>() {
    type Deferred = LiteralKeys<T>;
    // type Deferred = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends Literal ? K : never; }[keyof T]
}
```

And the compiler isn't able to do the sort of higher order reasoning that would let it decide if some specific value like `"name"` is compatible with such an unevaluated type for all `T extends IPerson`.  It treats that type as mostly opaque.  Since it can't verify that any value is assignable to it, it will generate an error if you do assign any value to it:

```
const name: Deferred = "name" // error!
```

There are some GitHub issues around the compiler not using [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) like `T extends IPerson` to help partially evaluate conditional types instead of completely deferring them.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#39787](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39787) and [microsoft/TypeScript#42077](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42077) for example.  Even if this were improved it might not be possible for the compiler to understand that `"name"` should always be assignable to `LiteralKeys<T>` when `T extends IPerson`.

---

In the absence of getting the compiler to understand what you already know, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler that you are sure that `"name"` is assignable and that it shouldn't worry:

```
export abstract class Person<T extends IPerson = IPerson> extends GraphNode<T> {
    setName(name: string) {
        (this as Person).set('name', name); // okay now
    }
}
```

Here I'm asserting that it can treat `this` as a `Person<IPerson>` instead of a `Person<T>`, at which point the relevant type for the `_key` parameter is `LiteralKeys<IPerson>` (which is just `"name"`) and not `LiteralKeys<T>` (which is ❓).  Of course when we type-assert things we should take extra care to make sure we are not accidentally lying to the compiler, since the burden of verifying type safety has shifted from the compiler (which can't handle it in this instance) to the human developer (who potentially can handle it but are known to be somewhat unreliable especially immediately before or after meals or bedtime).  In this case I think `this as Person` is probably harmless, especially because all `IPerson` subtypes will have to have a `name` property whose value is assignable to `string` and thus to `Literal`, but it's good to pause and triple check.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-1B2CUIQUSjlyOYEGAUg0-Qh-OEXiJ0nksIA+hFrKIADRQZN7NDUVXc0TGBEqW4AKigADpq1Ayw9mqaHOakJbrbbvlAHU73HUGqDo653FDRthhyQFAPBm6UB7vb75IjyWHgJ6VTCXqqSvMSyHyVAYcAunB3E6oL2cnDK8uYQByDc3rMbuHlSl4bQoEC7hu8Xhmi2dx1nSgbpel5GMzxGEgpFSED9CDXdlwAZQmKY0FAGFmBQ6YQFmUpOB3PcUUPY8r3DW9MIgSZsIfcZKNQ0Bny-E0fwVEglWYApFACAB3YCen0eE+A42hSJXNcb0Qgob0Y4TROQujsNvAAhJSAEVpL4IA)

Comment: Using `type Deferred = LiteralKeys<T>;` is a helpful way of testing/experimenting with this, and casting `this as Person` is a good workaround for me – and I'll keep an eye on the upstream TS issues. Thanks again!